# F# pattern match variable length separated words with first word a command

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to write this code in F#:

```
let run (command : string) = 
    let words = command.Split [|','|]
    match words.[0] with 
        | a when a .eignore "optionA" -> optionA words.[1] words.[2] words.[3]
        | a when a .eignore "optionB" -> optionB words.[1] words.[2] words.[3] words.[4] words.[5]
        | a when a .eignore "optionC" -> optionC words.[1] words.[2] words.[3] words.[4]
        | a when a .eignore "optionD" -> optionD words.[1] words.[2] words.[3] words.[4]
        | a when a .eignore "optionE" -> optionE words.[1] words.[2] words.[3]
        | a when a .eignore "optionF" -> optionF words.[1] words.[2]
        | a when a .eignore "optionG" -> optionG words.[1] words.[2] words.[3] words.[4]
        | _ -> ()
```

I am new to F# and I feel that this statement is quite repetitive and could be done a fair bit better, but Im not really sure where to start.

Basically what it does is runs a command, with the command being the first part of the comma separated string, and the remaining being the inputs: 
Example Input:

`optionA,1,2,A,Test`

Also `.eignore` is just a custom function for checking that the string is equal ignoring case.

Comment: What are `optionA`, `optionB`, etc.? Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including input and expected output.

Comment: The example input is listed above `optionA,1,2,A,Test` The `optionA` `optionB` are just methods. There doesnt need to be any output. The functions just run something.

Comment: If there doesn't need to be any output, you can refactor your function to this: `let run x = ()`.

Comment: That's clearly not what you want, but my psychic debugging powers don't tell me much more than that.

Comment: Its not so much that it doesnt work. The method above works, I just feel that it isnt the right or best way of trying to do what Im doing. 

All that Im trying to do is give a 'run' method the command to run. example: `optionA,1,2,A,Test`. Then the 'run' method will take the first item in the comma separated list `optionA` and run a specific method with the remaining parameters passed into it. This method could be anything, but in the code above it runs `optionA`. The parameters are in this example `1, 2, A, Test`

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [`Optional Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using composite pattern matching. You'll need an [active pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248) for the case-insensitive string comparison:

```
let (|EqIgnoreCase|_|) x y =
    if String.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    then Some ()
    else None
```

You can compose this `EqIgnoreCase` pattern into a standard [cons pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx):

```
let run (command : string) =
    let words = command.Split [|','|] |> Array.toList
    match words with
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionA" :: u :: v :: x :: _           -> optionA u v x
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionB" :: u :: v :: x :: y :: z :: _ -> optionB u v x y z
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionC" :: u :: v :: x :: y :: _      -> optionC u v x y
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionD" :: u :: v :: x :: y :: _      -> optionD u v x y
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionE" :: u :: v :: x :: _           -> optionE u v x
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionF" :: u :: v :: _                -> optionF u v
    | EqIgnoreCase "optionG" :: u :: v :: x :: y :: _      -> optionG u v x y
    | _ -> ()
```

It's easiest to use a cons pattern instead of an array pattern, because that enables you to easily ignore the tail of the list using the wildcard pattern (`_`).

Here are a few function calls:

```
> run "optionA,1,2,A,Test";;
optionA 1 2 A
val it : unit = ()

> run "optionB,1,2,A,Test,Foo";;
optionB 1 2 A Test Foo
val it : unit = ()

> run "OPTIONA,1,2,A,Test";;
optionA 1 2 A
val it : unit = ()

> run "OPTIONA,1,2,A";;
optionA 1 2 A
val it : unit = ()

> run "OPTIONA,1,2";;
val it : unit = ()
```

Notice that the last line has no console output because the list of arguments is too short.

Comment: This worked nicely. I wasn't aware of active pattern matching before. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the most repetition comes from passing the arguments to your functions. The obvious solution is to make them accept a string array:

```
type Command = { name : string; action : string array -> unit }
```

Of course, you can add some validating fields like number of arguments etc. Next, let's make some accessors for new type:

```
let cmdName = function {name = n; action = _} -> n
let cmdAction = function {name = _; action = a} -> a
```

And implement case-insensitive string comparison:

```
let icmp a b = String.Compare(a, b, true) = 0
```

Now we're ready to implement the main function:

```
type Class() as __ =
  member __.optionC(args : string array) = printfn "optionC!"
  static member optionD(args : string array) = printfn "optionD"

let run (command : string) = 
  let words = command.Split [|','|]
  [ { name = "optionA"; action = fun args -> printfn "%A" args }
    { name = "optionB"; action = fun _ -> printfn "optionB!" } 
    { name = "optionC"; action = fun args -> (new Class()).optionC(args) } 
    { name = "optionD"; action = Class.optionD } ]
  |> List.tryFind(cmdName >> (icmp words.[0]))                   // [1]
  |> Option.iter(cmdAction >> ((|>) words.[1..words.Length - 1]) // [2])
```

[1] We create the command list and try to find command with a name of first argument.

[2] Lastly, we pass all arguments to the action(`optionA` functions family effectively executing it).

Note that `Option.iter` will execute its payload only if the needed command was found.

Comment: I like this. Im just trying to fully understand how it at this stage. Haha.

Comment: With the actions, is it possible to have a custom method for each action. Example: `{ name = "optionA"; action = custom_method } `

So that the args are passed directly into the method.

Comment: see my update. also, try to prefer functions to methods(OO-style). all functions just need to have the same signature(although it's possible to have different with e.g. discriminated unions for action type).

Comment: Ahh ok, Awesome. I think I got it now. Thanks heaps! :)